# Python Method in a Class

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm trying to start using objects properly, I've built a deck of cards which is my object. I want to be able shuffle and deal cards from it. However I can't figure out how to get the shuffle method to work correctly or even if this is the best way to do it.

```
import itertools
import random

class Deck:
    '''Deck of cards to be used in a card game'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.faces = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', 'T', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4','3', '2']
        self.suits = ['c', 'd', 'h', 's']
        self.cards = set(itertools.product(self.faces, self.suits))

    def shuffle(self):
        self.cards = random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self):
        card = self.cards.pop()
        return card[0] + card[1]
```

Usage;

```
deck = Deck()
deck.shuffle()
deck.deal()
```

Comment: Should be using `list` instead of `set`.

Comment: `random.shuffle` modifies a list in-place; it returns `None`, not the shuffled list.

Comment: List and shuffle in place works. Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sets` are not ordered, you could use `list()` to obtain an ordered deck.
Furthermore `random.shuffle(l)` acts directly on the list and returns `None`, so you are overwriting the list with `None`.

```
import itertools
import random

class Deck:
    '''Deck of cards to be used in a card game'''
    def __init__(self):
        self.faces = ['A', 'K', 'Q', 'J', 'T', '9', '8', '7', '6', '5', '4','3', '2']
        self.suits = ['c', 'd', 'h', 's']
        self.cards = list(itertools.product(self.faces, self.suits))  # ordered deck
        # self.cards = set(itertools.product(self.faces, self.suits))  # unordered deck

    def shuffle(self):
        random.shuffle(self.cards)

    def deal(self):
        card = self.cards.pop()
        return card[0] + card[1]
```

Comment: There's no need for `set` at *all*, as `product` isn't going to produce any duplicates that need to be removed.

Comment: it needs only one between `list` or `set`. It didn't need `list(set( ... ))`, thanks for pointing it out